# Typescript require constrained generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

As per another stack overflow answer on the topic, you can require a generic to be passed to a function using the following:

```js
function contractType<T = void, U extends T = T>(value: unknown): U {
    return value as U
}
```

However I have a situation where I want to require a generic in this way, but with the generic being constrained to another type:

```js
function contractType<T extends Type = void, U extends T = T>(value: unknown): U {
    return value as U
}
```

This of course fails as void is not assignable to type 'Type'. Is there a way I can achieve a similar thing?

Comment: Could you add some example constraints?